# while deployment pod is going to Crashloopbackoff

Tags: kubernetes

I have a doubt regarding kubernetes. How to figure out the pod status while doing deployment using helm through Jenkins. Use case : while deployment pod is going to Crashloopbackoff and have to roll back to previous state. How to do that?

Comment: Hi there. You would apply the previous YAML configuration. Also `Crashloopbackoff` means the container is dying on startup. Watch the logs of the deployment `kubectl logs deployment/MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME -n MY_NAMESPACE -f`